# Deleting old schema locks from ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, schema-locks

I am going through old data on our GIS System (hoping to improve our file storage), and discovered that we have multiple schema locks on files that date back to 2017, 2018, and 2019.

A little bit of background: we use a shared file system (shared between 5 computers). The schema locks I've encountered have been from all of these computers, and I have confirmed with my co-workers that they don't have ArcGIS open. The format of these locks is .shp.COMPUTERNAME.NUMBERS.sr.lock (see picture below).

[image]

How do I get rid of these locks and what created them?

Comment: Those are standard lock files created on shapefiles while the map document is open.  They include the hostname and process id.  It's unlikely these lockfiles are still valid; you can confirm by trying to delete them (open files can't be deleted).

Comment: Thanks, I do know that locks are standard--I guess my question is why didn't these disappear when the map document was closed?There are hundreds of these locks throughout our system.

Comment: Usually because the application exited before doing so (crash, shutdown,...) . There isn't any way to prevent this, so you can set up a systematic job to attempt delete on files older than a week or two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit to Vince for the answer in the comments.

> How do I get rid of these locks?

- Delete the lock files from your filesystem.  Lock files that are still valid won't be deleted because they will be open.

> What created these locks?

- ArcGIS either crashed or closed before deleting the lock files, or it failed to delete them for some other reason (error 99999 [unexplained error] type of situation).

Comment: Even when correctly shut down, ESRI software commonly leaves file locks. This has been a long and frustrating problem for years. Try an internet search for "ESRI orphan locks".