# Unable to Package Data in ArcMap, LOCK files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, lock, arcgis-publisher

My organization still uses ArcReader (we are working on the transition to Pro) which is fine, but I tried to package some data today for our field guys and said there was an unexpected error in packaging. I closed out ArcMap on all other computers to make sure that wasn't the issue, but it still gave me the error. In the research I've done so far it looks like there may be issues with LOCK files being created. Has anyone else dealt with this? I can find some of the LOCK files, but I am hesitant to delete them because I don't know if it will corrupt or alter the data.

Comment: suggest https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346638/deleting-old-schema-locks-from-arcgis-desktop

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What was the precise error message that you received?